# Executing a line of code within gedit with bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to finish up this GUI I'm writing.

How would you execute a variable that is, for example, on line 3?

So for example:

```
var1='1'
var2='2'
var3='3'
```

From a terminal, I want to execute line 3 within a script that I wrote.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your script is `myscript.sh`

```
eval `head -n3 myscript.sh | tail -n1`
```

**Edit**

Explanation as requested:

- `head -n 3 myscript.sh` will retrieve the first 3 lines of your
  script
- These first three lines are piped (via the `|` operator) to `tail -n1`, which will give back only 1 line from the end of the input, so you get the last line of the first 3 lines - this is line 3
- `eval()` will simply run the resulting string, as if it were written in the script - so it runs the third line
- the backticks will make `eval()` run the **output** of the other commands, after running them

Comment: Im a guy who likes to know what everything means i dont mean to be demanding but what does each of the code mean?

Comment: The command substitution should be quoted. `$()` is preferred over backticks.

Comment: @EugenRieck Basically everyone. See [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: So `Basically everyone` is an obscure blog, that says *"It's easier to read. The character ` is difficult to read with small or unusual fonts. It's easier to type."* and else talks about nesting and backslashes, both of which are n/a here ... I use a german keyboard, so backticks are easy to write, and i use neither *small or unusual fonts* nor a CRT display from the iron age.

Comment: @EugenRieck Not a blog, and not obscure, (probably the very best collection of shell best-practices available anywhere), but the reasoning should be self-evident. Backticks are legacy syntax. The primary reason is escaping and nesting, but another reason which isn't listed is that it makes the syntax consistent with all other expansions parsed out of double-quotes, i.e., prefixed with a `$` sign. This is relatively uncontroversial.

Comment: @ormaaj Fine, so use it. I'm not stopping you.

Comment: @ormaaj Woohooo! Finally got you to downvote! I knew you could! Go for it! This is what life is for!

Comment: I'm trying to be helpful :) - but you haven't yet fixed the important issue, which is the [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Unquoted `eval ...` where ... is anything read from a file, not carefully  escaped, and possibly mixed with user-input, is wrong and possibly dangerous. Depending on the contents being read, execution of arbitrary code can be trivial. If you can fix that I'll gladly reverse the downvote. The backticks are only a minor style thing. Nobody will bite your head off over that unless there's ridiculous nesting/escaping going on.

Comment: @ormaaj By god, you ar *really* helpful! If you had actually **read** the OQ, you'd have a clearer picture of what I `eval()`: code that is meant to be executed as-is, this was the question, there is no user input involved. I suggest you keep your downvote, because I think you are plain wrong, as you are answering a different question. Besides, I simply don't mind - there are thousands of your kind out there, I can't educate them all.

Comment: The questioner specified that this was an artificial example and did not specify that the actual input would be predictable and sanitized. IMHO, it's wrong to make that assumption in any event and should just be done correctly automatically (in the rare event that you should be using `eval` to begin with). Believe me, there are far more of your kind - experienced programmers who assume this is a language that requires no learning, hence the abundance of horrifying tutorials and misunderstandings out there. I'm the one can't educate them all.

Comment: @ormaaj Ofcourse you know much better, *"How would you execute a variable that is, for example, on line 3"* together with the example ofcourse means everything else. You are welcome to submit your own answer, but since you are unable to do so (evidenced by you piling up all of 740 reputation in a year) you find more pleasure nitpicking others. Maybe in a few years or decades you might be knowledgable enough to be a useful member of the community - though I doubt it. Until then: happy nitpicking.

Comment: ROFL, You could have just taken the advice and left it but instead decided to take issue. You're obviously incapable of dealing with constructive criticism. But... reductio ad hominem is the last resort of the troll. Also note all but 1 of my answers are within the last three months. I have other things to do then spend all day on SO. I shall move on.

Comment: @ormaaj Excellent Idea, I couldn't have said it better: Just move on